# Отправка сообщения через VK API при запуске

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

C# практически не знаю, но встала задача реализовать приложение. Суть его в том, чтобы при запуске приложения(только один раз при запуске), через VK API, определенному пользователю отправлялось сообщение. Никаких авторизаций нет, есть только `id` кому отправить, токен и сообщение. Помогите с реализацией или посоветуйте пожалуйста статей на эту тематику, а то в интернете только сложные многоуровневые авторизации и отправки, чего мне не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй! Думаю, если б ты почитал документацию ВК-api, ты бы итак справился. Вот тебе метод отправки сообщения, принимающий на вход текст сообщения, ID получателя и твой токен. Если нужна помощь с его получением (токена) - пиши

```
private string SendMessage(string message, string id, string token)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        return client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send.xml?user_id={0}&message={1}&access_token={2}",id,HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message),token));
    }
    catch (WebException ex) { return ex.Message; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ, как мне кажется:
Создаете Stan alone приложение, получаете его ID.
Используете https://vk.com/dev/messages.send метод
Пример на PHP
`public function sendMessage($message){
        $this->method = 'messages.send';
        $this->params['access_token'] = '';
        $this->params['message'] = $message['text'];
        $this->params['user_id'] = $message['user_id'];
        return json_decode($this->executeRequest(),true);
    }`

`private function executeRequest(){
        return file_get_contents(VK_API.$this->method, false, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => http_build_query($this->params)
                )
            )));
    }`

Получить access token можно по ссылке:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ID_ВАШЕГО_ВК_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,messages&response_type=token&v=5.37
```

на c# писанины будет чуть больше, но суть такая же

Comment: не знаю уж, где там писанины больше хД

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то поможет, то вот код, который я использовал.

```c#
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Адрес ресурса, к которому выполняется запрос
            string url = "http://site.com/";

            // Создаём объект WebClient
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                // Выполняем запрос по адресу и получаем ответ в виде строки
                var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/164763)

Comment: @VAndrJ, это ответ. Почти ответ.